# How format nexus 4 before flashing new ROM

Tags: cyanogenmod, rom, formatting, lineageos

I have a Google Nexus 4 (mako) and I had installed cyanogen mode which accidentally showed a loop error message like "... has unfortunately closed" telling that several google apps and wizards had been closed.

**What I tried to DO:**

Now I want to re-install cyanogen. Because cyanogen is outdated I decided to flash the latest lineage ROM. My recovery (CWM version 6) is still unlocked, so I decided to do the fallowing:

1. Turn off the device
2. Go into boot loader mode by pressing Volume down and power and selecting to start recovery mode.
3. Wipe Data / Factory Reset
4. Enter side load mode and install lineage:
   adb sideload lineage-*.zip
5. Reboot.

After that lineage os booted and showed the same errors than my old cyanogen ROM. There are even error messages regarding some google apps, although they are not installed.

**Possible solution:**

It seems that the wipe data / factory reset did not delete the whole cyanogen mod. It seems just to delete user data. I think I need to format the whole device. Last time this maybe was done while unlocking the boot loader.

**Question:**

How to format Nexus 4 before flashing a new ROM.

Comment: Get your concepts right - recovery and bootloader are 2 different things.

Comment: Oh, ok, I read about the different and edited my question above here:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31158021/difference-between-fastboot-and-recoverymode-in-android#36739040

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CWM is long dead, let it stay that way.

You are advised to use the latest [TWRP recovery](https://dl.twrp.me/mako/), which has an interactive graphic interface, has a more powerful and thorough wipe function, and has an inbuilt file explorer so that you could just look inside `/system` to see if the wipe indeed worked (don't forget to mount `/system` before looking in, though).

After installing TWRP, select Advanced wipe: `/data`, `/cache` and `/system`. Actually it shouldn't be necessary to wipe `/system`, since newer Android ROMs overwrite the whole `/system` partition, but since you claim you need a full wipe, this will do.

Comment: Its dead? Ok, I'm going to flash TWRP.

Comment: Ok TWRP is done now I have this wonderful graphic interface. May you could now answer my question, how to format the device properly? TWRP offers an advanced wipe section, format data and Factory Reset...

Comment: Advanced wipe: `/data`, `/cache`, `/system`. Actually it shouldn't be necessary to wipe `/system`, since newer Android ROMs overwrite the whole `/system` partition, but since you claim you need a full wipe, this will do.

Comment: OK, thank you. Lineage and Gapps are now installed properly. Nevertheless some data like Music, Pictures and old Downloads are still on the device.

Comment: Unless you explicitly choose "internal storage" when wiping, recoveries are never supposed to wipe it, for obvious reasons.